# Why doesn't Over() work over the sum of a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get an overall sum to the TotalPrice but throws an error:

**Column** **'Invoices.ServicePrice' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SalesReport] 

        @FromDate date= '11-May-2018',
        @ToDate date= '05-Jun-2018'

AS
BEGIN
        Set @ToDate= case when @ToDate IS NULL then Convert(varchar(11), getdate(), 106) else @ToDate end

        Select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by b.BookingID order by b.BookingID) as ID, inv.InvoiceNo, 
        convert(varchar(11),inv.EntryDateTime,106) as EntryDateTime, Count(s.ServiceID) as TotalServices,
        SUM(inv.ServicePrice) as TotalPrice, SUM(inv.ServicePrice) over() as TotalRevenue
        from Invoices inv
        Inner Join Bookings b
        ON b.BookingID= inv.fk_BookingID
        Inner Join ZahidCarWashDB.dbo.Services s
        ON s.ServiceID= inv.fk_ServiceID
        where Convert(varchar(11), inv.EntryDateTime, 106) between @FromDate and @ToDate
        group by convert(varchar(11),inv.EntryDateTime,106), inv.InvoiceNo, b.BookingID



END
```

Comment: My guess is that the quantity has not yet available at the point where you call it.

Comment: Also you should never convert dates to strings for comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mixing window functions and aggregation functions can be tricky.  What you want is:

```
SUM(inv.ServicePrice) as TotalPrice,
SUM(SUM(inv.ServicePrice)) over () as TotalRevenue
```

Notice the extra `SUM()`.  The inner one is the `SUM()` on the row in the result set.  The outer one is the window function that sums the value over all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing down window function with aggregate functions is problem. You could take another aproach. Something like this:

```
 SELECT p.id, p.TotalPrice, p.TotalServices
        , SUM(p.TotalPrice) OVER (ORDER BY p.id) AS TotalPriceCumulative
        , SUM(p.TotalServices) OVER (ORDER BY P.id) AS TotalServicesCumulative
 FROM (
 SELECT b.BookingID AS ID -- or row_number() over (order By b.BookingID) AS ID
        , inv.TotalPrice, inv.TotalServices
 FROM Bookings AS b 
 INNER JOIN (SELECT inv1.fk_BookingID, SUM(inv.ServicePrice) as TotalPrice, Count(s.ServiceID) as TotalServices
                FROM Invoices AS inv1
                -- works only if one invoice is released for every invoice
                INNER Join ZahidCarWashDB.dbo.Services s ON s.ServiceID= inv1.fk_ServiceID
                where Convert(varchar(11), inv.EntryDateTime, 106) between @FromDate and @ToDate
             ) AS inv ON b.BookingID= inv.fk_BookingID
 ) AS p
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Gordon has the fix to your error.
You should not be converting date to varchar and do comparison.

```
    Set @ToDate = isnull(@ToDate, getdate());

    Select  ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by b.BookingID order by b.BookingID) as ID, 
            inv.InvoiceNo, 
            convert(varchar(11), inv.EntryDateTime, 106) as EntryDateTime, 
            Count(s.ServiceID)    as TotalServices,
            SUM(inv.ServicePrice) as TotalPrice, 
            SUM(inv.ServicePrice) over() as TotalRevenue
    from Invoices inv
    Inner Join Bookings b
       ON b.BookingID = inv.fk_BookingID
    Inner Join ZahidCarWashDB.dbo.Services s
       ON s.ServiceID = inv.fk_ServiceID
    where inv.EntryDateTime between @FromDate and @ToDate
    group by cast(inv.EntryDateTime as date)
           , inv.InvoiceNo
           , b.BookingID
```